# Extending AngularJS Templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the Play! Framework, I can do the following to DRY up my layout code:

*In **main.html**:*

```
<h1>This is main</h1>

#{doLayout /}

<div id="footer">Footer content</div>
```

*In **home.html**:*

```
 #{extends 'main.html' /}  

 <p>This is the home page content</p>
```

I would like to do the same in AngularJS i.e I would like to create an HTML file and have it inherit from another. I see that there is the ngInclude directive, but using it causes a lot of layout code duplication in my current application. If AngularJS does not natively support it, are there any other HTML templating solutions that do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`ng-view` directive updates the current element with the new data/template that comes from router, so you can make a generic layout and use `ng-view`, and if you still have a repetitive code; use `ng-include`.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at https://github.com/wmluke/angular-blocks. Looks like it has the thing you are looking for

Yeah i know this is an old question but I got here through googling the same thing so maybe It will help someone :)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer to this question.